# How to make ImageButton look pressed in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I am using **ImageButton** in my game and I want to show it touched or pressed. How can I accomplish this, I am new to **libgdx** framework.

```
TextureRegion btLeft = new TextureRegion(new Texture("NUMBEROFF.png"));
        Drawable drawableLeft = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(btLeft));
        buttonLeft = new ImageButton(drawableLeft);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different constructors for ImageButton that allows you to add multiple Drawables for when the button is in different states (up, down, and checked). But I prefer to use the ImageButtonStyle to do this.

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle.html

```
ImageButtonStyle style = new ImageButtonStyle();
style.imageUp = ...your drawable for up (normal) state
style.imageChecked = ...your drawable for checked state
style.imageDown = ...your drawable for down (pressed) state

ImageButton button = new ImageButton(style);
```